# The correct command in order to display the sound GUI

Tags: command-line, sound, gui

what is the terminal command  one should  give in order to summon the original ubuntu sound GUI of ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 0):

Depends on which sound system are you using. Under 18.04 is commonly used PulseAudio, so you can simply write:

```
pavucontrol
```

In your terminal or favorite launcher in order to see this:

[image]

Which is one of the most commong "Sound GUI's" used under Ubuntu 18.04

Please add more information to your question if you expected something else.